# Prove that if $P$ and $Q$ are projective and finitely generated $R$-modules then $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(P,Q)$ is projective and finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, projective-module

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $P$ and $Q$ are projective and finitly generated $R$-modules. Prove that $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(P,Q)$ is projective and finitely generated.

suppose I proved that  $Hom_{R}(P,Q)$ is finitely generated thus it's generators will be $\left \langle \varphi_{1} ,\varphi_{2} ,...\varphi_{s}  \right \rangle$,consider this diagram:
[image]

for each $\varphi _{i}$ , $1\leq i\leq s$ we have $f(\varphi _{i})=b_{i},
b_{i}\in B$.

because $g$ is surjective for these $f(\varphi _{i})$ there are $a_{i}\in A$ that $g(a_{i})=f(\varphi _{i})$ .

I define $h(\varphi _{i})=a_{i}$ so $g(h(\varphi _{i}))=g(a_{i})=f(\varphi _{i})$
thus  $Hom_{R}(P,Q)$ is projective.

I think this solution is right.
now I don't know how I must show that $Hom_{R}(P,Q)$ is finitely generated.

a hint or a suggestion will be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $P$ is projective and finitely generated then $P$ is a direct summand in a free module of finite rank, say $n$. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(P,Q)$ is a direct summand of $Q^n$, so it is projective and finitely generated. (If the conclusion is too abrupt you can do the same for $Q$:  it is a direct summand in a free module of finite rank, say $m$. In the end, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(P,Q)$ is a direct summand of $R^{mn}$.)

Comment: thank you very much for your solution .